# Qt : Write in file

Tags: c++, qt

I'm learning how QT is working. I have this little code :

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QWidget fenetre;
fenetre.setFixedWidth(400);
fenetre.setFixedHeight(400);

QPushButton *bouton = new QPushButton("Quit", &fenetre);
bouton->setFixedHeight(50);
bouton->setFixedWidth(100);
bouton->move(170,310);


QLabel *label = new QLabel("Something", &fenetre);
label->move(30,200);
QLineEdit *line = new QLineEdit(&fenetre);
line->move(200,200);

QWidget::connect(bouton, SIGNAL(clicked()),qApp, SLOT(quit()));

fenetre.show();
```

I'm wondering how could I put the content of `QLineEdit` label in a file (.txt) continuously.
The goal is to keep what the user put in the `QLineEdit` box in a text file when the program is finished.

Thanks

Comment: `QLabel` or `QLineEdit` ?

Comment: My bad, I meant the content of the QLineEdit that can be modified by the user, Yes.  Sorry :/

Comment: So have you attempted to store the string from line->text() into file when the program is finished?

Comment: You want the contents written to a file when the button is clicked?

Comment: I try with no success to insert a kind of function who put line->text() into the text file in the slot. How could I do that ?

Comment: Yes when the button is clicked that good too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating/writing into a new file in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916193/creating-writing-into-a-new-file-in-qt)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`QFile`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) and [`QTextStream`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html) to write to a file, when [`QLineEdit::textChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qlineedit.html#textChanged) signal is emitted as follows:

```
QObject::connect(line, &QLineEdit::textChanged, [](const QString& text) {
    QFile file("output.txt");

    if(file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)) {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        stream << text;
        file.close();
    }
});
```

The code above will connect a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to the `QLineEdit::textChanged` signal. The `text` argument of that lambda will be the changed content of your `line`. The code block inside the lambda simply rewrites the `"output.txt"` with the received `text`.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering how could I put the content of QLineEdit label in a file (.txt) **continuously**. The goal is to keep what the user put in the QLineEdit box in a text
>   file when the **program is finished**.

I can interpret these words as either you probably want to save `QLineEdit` content when your application is *about to close* or you want to save it *"on a fly"*, immidiately as user types something to `QLineEdit`. In both cases you can use some `save()` function like this:

```
void save(const QString &text)
{
    QFile f("out.txt");
    bool ok = f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    if(!ok) {
        qDebug() << "open file error!";
        return;
    }

    QTextStream stream(&f);
    stream << text;
    f.close();
}
```

and then apply one of these `connect` functions in your `main`:

```
// save on type
QObject::connect(line, &QLineEdit::textChanged, [line](const QString &text) {
    save(text);
});

// save on application close.
QObject::connect(&app, &QApplication::aboutToQuit, [line]() {
    save(line->text());
});
```

It is enough to use one of these `connect`s depending on your needs.

Note: `&QApplication::aboutToQuit` signal is emmitted when your application is closing either by pressing standard windows "Close" button or by pressing your custom "Quit" button.

Comment: @Akira Obviously. But that also means that you perform disk operation each time you edit `QLineEdit`. And sometimes it is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) to Read/Write data in files text/binary format.

Button Press to save data:

```
void MainWindow::on_btnSaveData_clicked()
{
    writeDataInFile(ui->lineEdit->text());
}
```

Function Save Data:

```
void MainWindow::writeDataInFile(QString data)
{
    QString filePath = "D:/Your Path";
    QFile writeFile(filePath);
    if(!writeFile.open(QFile::Append | QFile::Text))
    {
        // Can't Open File.
    }
    else
    {
        if(data.length() > 0)
        {
            QTextStream in(&writeFile);
            in << data << "\r";
        }
    }
    writeFile.close();
}
```

This function gets a `QString`, opens a file (`filePath`) and appends data at the end of your file.

You can modify function and send `QByteArray` to the function or a Vector.